# The official document about Leaderboards of Play Games Services uses deprecated startActivityForResult

Tags: android, google-play-games, startactivityforresult

Below code is from Google's [official document](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards#displaying_a_leaderboard) about Leaderboards of Play Games Services (converted into Kotlin):

```
private fun showLeaderboard() {
    PlayGames.getLeaderboardsClient(this).allLeaderboardsIntent
        .addOnSuccessListener { intent ->
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
        }
}
```

Android Studio says:

> 'startActivityForResult(Intent!, Int): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`ActivityResultContracts`**](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#custom) instead of deprecated `startActivityForResult`.

```
private val leaderboardsResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
) { /* do nothing */ }

private fun showLeaderboard() {
    PlayGames.getLeaderboardsClient(this).allLeaderboardsIntent
        .addOnSuccessListener { intent ->
            leaderboardsResultLauncher.launch(intent)
        }
}
```

The Leaderboards document says:

> Notice that even though **no result is returned**, we have to use
> startActivityForResult so that the API can obtain the identity of the
> calling package.

So, in this situation (as for Leaderboards), you have nothing to do with the result in your `ActivityResultContracts`.